# Java downloading files sometimes result in CRC

Tags: java

I've written code to automatically download a batch of files using an InputStream and a FileOutputStream.
The code is very straightforward:

```
is = urlConn.getInputStream();
fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

eventBus.fireEvent(this, new DownloadStartedEvent(item));

int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}

eventBus.fireEvent(this, new DownloadCompletedEvent(item));
```

At first sight this works very well, files get downloaded without any problems, however,
occasionally while trying to extract a batch of downloaded rar files, extraction fails with one of the rar parts having a CRC error.

As this happened a few times already, although not consistently, I started to suspect that something in this code is not correct/optimal.
It will be helpful to know that there are 4 downloads executing concurrently using the JDK FixedThreadPool mechanism:

```
execService.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (item.getState().equals(DownloadCandidateState.WAITING)) {
                        Downloader downloader = new Downloader(eventBus);
                        downloader.download(item, item.getName());
                    }
                }
});
```

But because every download thread uses a new instance of the Downloader class, I believe this problem is not a side effect of concurrency?
Any ideas if this occasional CRC error has to do with the code or if it has to do with something else?

***UPDATE***

I can verify that the file size of a problematic file is correct.
I also did a diff (on linux) on the automatically downloaded file and the manually downloaded file.
The filesize is the exact same for both files, however, diff says that the binary content differs between the 2 files:

Binary files file.rar and file(2).rar differ

***UPDATE 2***

I used a visual binary diff tool and could see that a sequence of 128 bytes was different, somewhere in the middle of the file. I don't understand how that could happen, as the file being downloaded doesn't change and it is being read byte per byte using an input stream. Any ideas??

Comment: Can you approve that the remote files are not corrupted? Perhaps it's not your download but the files.

Comment: you probably need to close the inputstream after reading

Comment: @PartlyCLoudy: yes when I download the particular file manually, it is correct

@seanizer: the input stream is being closed in the finally block, but I left that part out for the sake of brevity

Comment: Are you using an UDP or TCP connection?

Comment: @Esko: there's no such thing as a "UDP connection". Besides, the OP is quite clearly using a URLConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seemed to have been the Linux atheros driver for my NIC.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Apache's HttpClient if you don't want to handle that entity streaming yourself. It's a well written and documented library. There are several usable entity / entity wrapper classes [available](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html).

Here you can have a look at entity retrieval: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e152

Answer (score 1):

You should run a diff (unix tool) comparing the original with the result to find out what has actually changed. You May see a pattern right away.

Comment: I did a diff with a problem case.
The size of the automatically downloaded file and the manually downloaded file is the same, however, diff says that the binary contents are not the same:

Binary files file.rar and file(2).rar differ

Comment: I used a visual binary diff tool and could see that a sequence of 128 bytes was different, somewhere in the middle of the file.
I don't understand how that could happen, as the file being downloaded doesn't change and it is being read byte per byte using an input stream.
Any ideas??

Comment: Is that all?  Is the bytes almost the same (moved a bit or byte) or is it a copy of an earlier block?  My guess would be an error in the library responsible for lifting the bytes fron the network layer to the recipient.

Comment: Thorbjoern, do you mean that this problem could be OS related?
I did a diff again on another problem case, and again there are only 128 bytes different between the 2 files.
At least that's a clear pattern, but I don't know what to make of it

Comment: No, I think there is an error in the java library giving you those bytes.

Comment: Well I'm using OpenJDK 6, I will try again withthe Sun JDK as soon as I have the chance.

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me.
I don't see which library you mean, I'm using 100% standard JDK API in that downloader.
Can you please elaborate? Can I change anything for testing?

Comment: I reread your question.  I thought you were using a library to pull the bytes off the network. if you really are just getting a URLConnection and then using it, then try with the Sun JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by flushing (or closing) the FileOutputStream

Comment: Both input stream and output stream are being closed in the finally block, in that order

Comment: Are you closing it BEFORE firing the event?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct provided everything is closed and no exceptions are thrown. The problem lies elsewhere, probably in the original files.